# how to write the class code to consume the webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, gridview

i am a newbiest in c#, i am doing web service and got stuck , and have a problem. So i have to project A and B. After i create a web service in project A, i want project B to consume the web service Project A has create. i know that i have to add web reference but what about after that? what code should i put i the class ? and the data i call from database and i want the data consume through web service put in a gridview in project B, how should i write the code??? i am doing in  visualstudio 2010

really need urgent help

hope anyone can reply me asap!!thanks

Answer (score 1):

when you adding web reference you should give a name to it by using this name in your code you can access to the service and consuming service functions as well

Comment: then how to write the code to consume the function after i have add the reference

Comment: like a when calling a method from a class

Answer (score 0):

Watch video #42 here:  http://www.asp.net/general/videos

Answer (score 0):

When you add web references, Visual Studio automatically generates strongly-typed proxy classes for you, base on the definition of the web service. In other words, after adding a web reference, you can straight-away use the generated proxy classes to communicate with the web service.

Below is an excerpt from [Creating and using Web Services with the .NET framework and Visual Studio.Net](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebservices/DotNetWebServices.asp) that explains in details what a web reference is:

> Visual Studio.Net Web References are
>   proxy classes created on the client to
>   connect to the Web Service running on
>   the server. Inside of the IDE Web
>   references automatically generate code
>   and insert hidden files into your
>   project. This is required because .Net
>   is type safe and in order to compile
>   code that uses the Web Service, the
>   client has to know the method
>   signature of each method that is
>   called.
>
> This is nice as it provides full
>   IntelliSense support in the
>   development environment. However it
>   also means that you need to refresh
>   the Web Reference whenever the Web
>   Service interface changes.
>
> The generated proxy class code is
>   stored in the \WebReferences folder
>   beneath the application directory.
>   There is one source file class for
>   each Web Reference you create by the
>   name of the class you publish.
>   Although you can look at the source
>   you shouldn’t change this code as it
>   will be overwritten next time you
>   update the Web Reference.
>
> To use a Web Reference simply add the
>   namespace of the Web Reference. By
>   default it’ll be
>   YourClientNameSpace.ServerClassNameSpace.
>   Make sure you add this namespace to
>   your list of namespaces (using … in C#
>   or imports … in VB).

You are also recommended to read the article as it has an in-depth discussio of web service in .Net.